# How can I change Image in the URL and still make sure old emails that are sent is not affected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-email, sendgrid, email-attachments

Our application will send the emails for customers on different events. These emails has placeholder where we need to display a promotion banner. Marketing team asking us to make this as dynamic. That means there will be a common url, and team will change the image in that URL for every month whenever new promotion comes in.

Now my requirement is,
Say Dec 01 2021, Marketing team has updated a new image in that URL.

1. Now all my emails that will send after Dec 01 2021 should have this new image.
2. Also, All the Emails that are already sent to customer before Dec 01 2021 (until Nov 30 2021) should not get affected and if customer opens them, they should still see the old image only.

(Note: Both new and old emails will have same IMAGE URL, but only image in that URL will be changed). All our applications are .NET applications.

Comment: Two emails with the same URL showing a different image? It’s not possible. You need a different URL per event.

Comment: Is there no possible ways? like copying the image into Email something like that?

Also, So Old Images should be there in the OLD IIMAGE URL forever to facilitate that customers who already received this email earlier dont have any issues ?

Comment: If you embed a fixed standalone image, obviously it can't be changed. If you embed a fixed URL to an external image and change the image, it will change. I got the impression from your quetion that you were embedding a URL in the email.

Comment: There's no point sending emails with embedded image urls; it's probably universal now that clients won't load them because they're used by spammers to track who has opened an email. Rewrite your code to retrieve the image from the url and embed it in the outgoing email. This will massively inflate the size of every email, and even inflate the image to 4/3 of its original size because of base64 encoding.. so I recommend to compress the image too, or impose some restrictions at source, because if the marketing people get their way everyone will be receiving 10 megabyte 4K company logos..

Comment: The nuisance of it is, there are a few different ways to embed images (eg encoded multipart form, inline b64 in src= attribute) and support in mail clients isn't universal. If you want to persist with the url route you'll have to use a different url per campaign, which will help the urls look even more spammy and help even more of your emails trigger junk mail filters.. No good solution to this one; spammers have ruined it I'm for everyone. You could consider not sending email newsletters(who reads them?);put your campaigns on your after-login pages then you can target users who do log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

As Nick and Caius have said in the comments, you cannot achieve this with a single URL. If you change the image behind a URL, then old emails that use that URL will update with the new image when they are opened.

Instead you should either use different URLs each time. Or, as Caius points out, embedded image URLs may not load. So, you can also attach the image to the email and embed it. Base 64 embedding is useful, but it does bloat the email size, especially as it bloats the image size itself.

I personally prefer adding images as attachments and then embedding them in the content by referring to them via CID, or Content-ID. The details on how to do that are in this post on [embedding images in emails](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/). But the idea is that you give the attachment a `cid` attribute and then in your HTML refer to that cid in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag:

```html
<img src="cid:myimagecid"/>
```